# @ngrx/store dispatch working from component but not working from @ngrx/effect

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

below code works when dispatch from component 
but not work(i mean update store but not in ui) on ngrx/effect

favourite-product.reducer.ts::

```
case fromFavouriteProduct.ADD_TO_FAVOURITE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS: {
  state.data.push(action.payload);/*working when dispetch from component but not working when dispatch form @effect*/
  // state.data=[] /*but its work always*/
  // state.data=action.payload /*its also  working  always*/
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    loaded: true,
  }
}
```

favourite-product.effect.ts::

```
@Effect()
addFavouriteProduct$ = this.actions$.ofType(favouriteProductActions.ADD_TO_FAVOURITE_PRODUCT).pipe(
    switchMap((action: any) => {

        return this.favouriteProductService
            .insert(action.payload)
            .pipe(
                map(result => new favouriteProductActions.AddToFavouriteProductSuccess(result)),
                catchError(error => of(new favouriteProductActions.LoadFavouriteProductFail(error)))
            );

    })
)
```

Comment: recommend to put a break point and see!

Comment: Do you have devtools configured?

Comment: yes , everything is working fine except this effect ,

Comment: Are you using `OnPush` strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem hurray 
its just a silly one :(
though state is immutable object

```
 let data = state.data.slice();

        data.push(action.payload);

        return <FavouriteProductState>{
            ...state,
            loading: false,
            loaded: true,
            data

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing inputs to service, recommend to use map to get payload

```
@Effect()
addFavouriteProduct$ = this.actions$.ofType(favouriteProductActions.ADD_TO_FAVOURITE_PRODUCT).pipe(
    map((action) => action.payload),
    switchMap((payload) => {

        return this.favouriteProductService
            .insert(payload)
            .pipe(
                map(result => new favouriteProductActions.AddToFavouriteProductSuccess(result)),
                catchError(error => of(new favouriteProductActions.LoadFavouriteProductFail(error)))
            );
```

Comment: try this and let me know !

Comment: its not working brother! my service is calling properly 
everuthing is fine even devtool is showing update in store 
but only ui is not responding once but calling twice working  ,
even console.log(action.payload)  in reducer is consoling well,
even if i set state.data=[]  is working well, only state.data.push(action.payload )is not working .
but when i dispatch from component the everything is fine

Comment: @Effect()
    addFavouriteProduct$ = this.actions$.ofType(favouriteProductActions.ADD_TO_FAVOURITE_PRODUCT).pipe(
        switchMap((action: any) => of(new favouriteProductActions.AddToFavouriteProductSuccess(action.payload)))
    )


is working  but when service call is not working

Comment: can you share it some where?

Comment: where is you map to payload => map((action) => action.payload),

Comment: i tried every  possible way from your suggestion or even all documentation on google.
it works when i click twice
if you have time can i explain ?